# Relative postitioning not working

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a website on which I'm trying to float a div to be vertically centered inside it's parent div. The code I've used is basically this;

```
#box_to_be_floated_vertically {
    position:relative;
    top:50%;
}
```

It looks like it should work, but it doesn't?

For my example, look here: http://www.dronnoc.com/temp/index.php
If you look on here, it's the div floating on the side of the sidebar, with the ID `#handle`. I've tried also using `#sidebar > #handle` but that made no difference.

Any ideas or solutions? I've struggled with this for days.

**EDIT**

I'd like to point out that in my example site, if I physically put in a pixel height in the `top` property, it works fine. The issue lies when I try to use a percentage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
#box_to_be_floated_vertically {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -XXpx;
    }
```

`XX` - height of the element divided by 2

The container must have `position:relative;`

Comment: This got it. I thought I'd tried it before, but apparently not this combination. Thanks heaps.

Answer (score 0):

You may try **[Dead Centre](http://www.wpdfd.com/editorial/thebox/deadcentre4.html)**

Hope this helps..

Comment: Thanks, but this uses _absolute_ positioning, when I need _relative_. But, aside from that it would be extremely useful. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. Consider upvoting and (or) accepting my answer if it is helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in percentage i workout.

```
 #handle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 70%;
    }
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it won't always be at `70%` on my page. The content length will be varied, as will the browser size.